# KNET Payment Gateway Integration in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, payment-gateway

I need to integrate KNET payment gateway in a Next.js application. But I wasn't able to find any documentation or example for that.

Can anyone please help me and provide any idea how to integrate the KNET in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, here is how I was able to integrate KNET in Next.js:

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto'

const pkcs5Pad = (text: string) => {
  const blocksize = 16
  const pad = blocksize - (text.length % blocksize)

  return text + pad.toString().repeat(pad)
}

const aesEncrypt = (text: string, key: string) => {
  const AES_METHOD = 'aes-128-cbc'
  const content = pkcs5Pad(text)

  try {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(AES_METHOD, new Buffer(key), key)
    let encrypted = cipher.update(content)

    encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()])

    return `${encrypted.toString('hex')}`
  } catch (err) {
    /* empty */
  }
}

const aesDecrypt = (text: string) => {
  const AES_METHOD = 'aes-128-cbc'
  const key = process.env.termResourceKey

  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(
    AES_METHOD,
    new Buffer(key as string),
    key as string
  )
  const encryptedText = new Buffer(text, 'hex')
  let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText)

  decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()])

  return decrypted.toString()
}

const initiateKnetPayment = () => {
  const kpayUrl = process.env.kpayUrl // https://www.kpay.com.kw/kpg/PaymentHTTP.htm for production or https://www.kpaytest.com.kw/kpg/PaymentHTTP.htm for test
  const tranportalId = process.env.tranportalId
  const tranportalPassword = process.env.tranportalPassword
  const termResourceKey = process.env.termResourceKey
  const responseUrl = process.env.kpayResponseUrl
  const errorUrl = process.env.kpayErrorUrl

  const paramData = {
    currencycode: '414',
    id: tranportalId,
    password: tranportalPassword,
    action: '1',
    langid: 'AR',
    amt: 20, // amount
    responseURL: responseUrl,
    errorURL: errorUrl,
    trackid: Math.random(),
    udf3: 12345678 // 8 digit numeric value as customer identifier
  }

  let params = ''

  Object.keys(paramData).forEach((key) => {
    params += `${key}=${paramData[key as keyof typeof paramData]}&`
  })

  const encryptedParams = aesEncrypt(params, termResourceKey)

  params = `${encryptedParams}&tranportalId=${tranportalId}&responseURL=${responseUrl}&errorURL=${errorUrl}`

  const url = `${kpayUrl}?param=paymentInit&trandata=${params}`

  Router.push(url)
}
```